# Error 800A01A8 Object required; I have a string

Tags: string, object, vbscript

At the end of this VBScript code `Set dataRequest = objStream.ReadText` gives an error

> Object required '[string: "<STATUS><IP>"]'
>   Code 800A01A8

I don't know how to tell it that `dataRequest` is intended to be a string.

```
Dim dataRequest
Set objFSO=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("c:\status.xml", 1)
Set objStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
objStream.Type = 2
objStream.CharSet = "ASCII"
objStream.Open
objStream.WriteText objFile.ReadAll
objStream.Position = 0
Set dataRequest = objStream.ReadText
```

Comment: `Set dataRequest = objStream.ReadText` -> `dataRequest = objStream.ReadText`. Don't use the `Set` keyword if you're not assigning an object. What are you trying to do here anyway? You're just writing text to a stream, then reading the exact same text back from the stream. You could just as well drop the stream object and do `dataRequest = objFile.ReadAll` to get the same result.

Comment: Great thanks now I understand...